# Get all keys of Json as list directly from Git Repo

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

For my Jenkins pipeline I want to populate all the keys in Json which is in GitRepo as Extended Choice parameters.

```
[$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Select an option', name: 'Option', randomName: 'choice-parameter-112', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ''], script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false,
  script: '''
      //What should I write here in this block?
      return keys
  ''']]]
```

Basically all I need is a curl call that I can make from the above block to get single file from Git using the Git Credential ID(I've stored my user name and password as credential id in Git)

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent case which boils down to this:

You can't issue a call to `sh` unless you have a `node`. To have a node, you need to run a pipeline. To run a pipeline, you need to figure out the parameters. To figure out this parameter, you need to issue a call to `sh`. See the problem?

To overcome the problem, you can cheat the system by running another (small) pipeline before the main one, e.g.

```
node('master') {
    stage('read file') {
        def file_contents = sh (returnStdout: true, script: "curl myrepo/myfile.json")
        def parsed_data = readJSON text: file_contents
    }
}
```

and then

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
```

etc.

Comment: Can you give me what is the curl command for getting single file from git repo using Jenkins Credential ID?